# Is there a Windows 10 command that acts like Win + D, but only for the current screen?

Tags: windows-10

I recently got a second monitor and I am used to the <kbd>Win+D</kbd> shortcut.

Both the shortcut and the button next to the clock minimize *all* windows across screens. Is there a way I can minimize all windows on the *current** screen?

* I am not familiar with the proper terminology, I will clarify that by current screen I mean the screen that has the current active window.

---

Edit in hope that this question gets reopened:

I am looking for a solution that works on **Windows 10**. My question is marked as a duplicate and the original question contains no answer to this (my) question.

Comment: @harrymc This questions is exactly like mine, but it is far away from answered. None of the suggested options in the accepted answer (your answer) work for windows 10. I would like my question to be reopened in order to receive answers that actually work. Thank you!

Comment: This is not a good reason for opening a duplicate. You should update your post to differentiate it from the other, then ask for it to be reopened using the "reopen" button.

Comment: @harrymc I edited my question to specify that I am looking for a solution for **windows 10** (both in the content of the question and the title). I do not have such button "reopen".

Comment: Can you try Win+M?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need.  "I am not familiar with the proper terminology, I will clarify that by current screen I mean the screen that has the current active window." - I cannot make heads or tails out of this sentence.

Comment: @grawity minimizes all windows on all screens.

Comment: @Ramhound I mean that if I have Chrome on Monitor #1 and Skype on Monitor #2 and I am currently typing a message in Skype (meaning Skype's window is on focus) when I press `Win+D` (or another shortcut) Skype is minimized while Chrome stays as it is.